# Why textfield data not fetched from tableViewCell when i click button in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitableview

if i click the button NSLog shows NULL value, it’s not getting the data from textfield why?.......

Delegate methods working properly.................

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cellID"];
  if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    self.nameTextField = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    self.nameTextField.frame =CGRectMake(25, 0, 300, 50);
    self.nameTextField.placeholder = @"Name";
    self.nameTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    [cell addSubview:self.nameTextField];
    self.nameTextField.delegate = self;

  return cell;
 }
  if (indexPath.row == 1) {

    self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    self.button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 10, 135, 50);
    [self.button setTitle:@"StoreData" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:self.button];

    return cell;
  }

 return nil;
}

-(void)buttonClicked:(id) sender {

  if (sender == self.phoneTextField) {

    self.nameString = self.nameTextField.text;
  }

  NSLog(@"Name : %@", self.nameString);
}
```

Comment: is it going inside if statement on button click?

Comment: yes, it's printing OutPut: Name : (null)

Comment: Here the sender is the button so it will never enter the condition
sender = self.button

Comment: Where do you declare `phoneTextField`? It looks like the code will never reach inside the if (in `buttonClicked:`). Note also that you're always initializing new cells (along with initalizing and re-assigning `self.nameTextField` and `self.button`), even when you simply scroll your table (`cellForRowAtIndexPath:` can - and usually is - called multiple times).

Comment: Why sender=self.phoneTextField how is it going inside?? Is there any tag value ? If yes where is sender.tag??

Comment: if i write code like this also it's prints only NULL -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    
    NSLog(@"Delegate method called");
    
    if (textField == self.phoneTextField) {
        
        self.nameString = self.nameTextField.text;
        NSLog(@"Name : %@", self.nameString);
    }
    
    NSLog(@"Out side : %@", self.nameString);
     return YES;
}

Comment: @ Tushar Sharma i am not using any tags

Comment: @VadlaniMarking if you don't use any tags, how will the code "know" which textField you are referring to? you can/should at least add the tag of the row, and that should fix it

Comment: self.nameTextField.tag = 0;         -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    
    NSLog(@"Delegate method called");
    
    if (textField.tag == 0) {
        
        self.nameString = self.nameTextField.text;
        NSLog(@"Name : %@", self.nameString);
    }
    
    NSLog(@"Out side : %@", self.nameString);
     return YES;
}
 Now OutPut : Delegate method called
 Name : 
 Out side :

Comment: @ Ricardo Alves  now i am using tags but it's printing empty output why?

Answer (score 1):

the `parameter` in the `action function` is the button not the `textField`

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id) sender {
    if (sender == self.button) {
        self.nameString = self.nameTextField.text;
      }
  NSLog(@"Name : %@", self.nameString);
}
```

Comment: yes, it's working... but it print's output : Name :  Out side Name :

Comment: it's not printing data

Comment: it's printing empty output why?

Comment: Because self.nameTextField.text is empty string

Comment: `if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    self.nameTextField = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    self.nameTextField.frame =CGRectMake(25, 0, 300, 50);
    self.nameTextField.placeholder = @"Name";
    self.nameTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    [cell addSubview:self.nameTextField];
    self.nameTextField.delegate = self;

  return cell;
 }`

you don't set here the self.nameTextField.text you are setting the placeholder only